# Using GCM for iOS APN

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, apn

I am trying to create push notification in my iOS app using the GCM. If I want to submit the app to App Store, would Apple approve or reject my app?

Comment: They may reject it for other reasons, but I doubt GCM would be one of them

Comment: I think nobody can tell you if your app gets rejected, because we don`t know your app but it will not be rejected because of GCM.

Comment: Thanks to Flexicoder and LoVo for the answer